# What is a well-formed UTF-16 string?

Tags: unicode

I need some help understanding the concept of a well-formed UTF-16 string as mentioned on these two paragraphs at [Chapter 2: General Structure 2.7 Unicode String](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode6.2.0/ch02.pdf):

"Depending on the programming environment, a Unicode string may or may not be required to be in the corresponding Unicode encoding form. For example, strings in Java, C#, or ECMAScript are Unicode 16-bit strings, *but are not necessarily well-formed UTF-16 sequences*. In normal processing, it can be far more efficient to allow such strings to contain code unit sequences that are *not well-formed UTF-16*—that is, isolated surrogates. Because strings are such a fundamental component of every program, checking for isolated surrogates in every operation that modifies strings can create significant overhead, especially because supplementary characters are extremely rare as a percentage of overall text in programs worldwide.

Whenever such strings are specified to be in a particular Unicode encoding form—even one with the same code unit size—the string must not violate the requirements of that encoding form. For example, *isolated surrogates in a Unicode 16-bit string are not allowed when that string is specified to be well formed UTF-16*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The paragraph explains it for UTF-16; not well-formed means the string contains isolated surrogate codeunits.

That is, there are certain code units which are only valid when they appear in pairs. A code unit in the range [0xD800-0xDFFF] must occur only in pairs where the first must be in the range [0xD800-0xDBFF] and the second must be in the range [0xDC00-0xDFFF]. If a string does not obey this requirement then it is not well-formed.

Comment: Ok, but what does that mean ? "In normal processing, it can be far more efficient to allow such strings to contain code unit sequences that are not well-formed UTF-16—that is, isolated surrogates."

Comment: @user1042389 I've already answered what 'isolated surrogates' means. So what other part of that sentence are you asking about?

Comment: What would the purpose of a string that contains an unpaired surrogate?

Comment: @user1042389 None, it's not valid. The purpose of allowing such an invalid string to occur is that preventing it costs time and effort that may not be worth spending. For example the operation to insert a character into a string would have to do a bunch of checks to make sure there won't be any isolated surrogates in the result. Since there almost never will be, performance will be hurt for almost no benefit.

Comment: I don't understand when you say a bunch of checks. If you have a low-surregate, you just check the next 16 bits if its a high surrogate or end of string. What is the big deal here ?

Comment: @user1042389 "What is he big deal here?" If you've got performance to spare then maybe you can afford that. Not everyone does. Furthermore, the checks may provide no value for a particular program that uses other mechanisms to prevent the invalid data. Building the most basic parts of the library to be slow means it's not possible to build fast programs on top of that. Better than paying extra to over-constrain a program is to have layers where each layer provides only the minimal guarantees it has to. That way programs don't have to pay costs for things they don't need.